# jQuery plugin documentation with JSDoc

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I'm wondering how to documenting jQuery plugin by using JSDoc? My code is:

```
   /**
     * The default configurations of comments
     * @typedef {Object} CommentConfig
     ...
     */

   /**
     * Show comments
     * @method comments
     * @version 1.0.1
     * @param {CommentConfig} options Configuration of comment
     */
    $.fn.comments = function (options) {
        // ..
    }
```

I want `@method` is `$.fn.comments` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Acording to [JSDoc3 docs](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-external.html) you should use `@external` in your case:

```
/**
 * The jQuery plugin namespace.
 * @external "jQuery.fn"
 * @see {@link http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring The jQuery Plugin Guide}
 */

/**
 * Show comments
 * @function external:"jQuery.fn".comments
 */
```